# Rails observer still fetching the default values instead of updated value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `Variant` and `OptionValue`. `variant.name` gets updated when `option_value` is added to variant model, but when option_value is updated the variant.name is not updated, I have created a sweeper for this and added an observer for option_value. When option_value attribute is updated then the control goes to the sweeper `after_update` method, but the value of the argument `option_value` is not the updated one but the default value which is set. I checked the `id` of both the values in sweeper as well as in the spec and they are different.
op_spec.rb

```
   it 'updates names when option_value is updated' do
      option_value_1 = create(:option_value, value: 'Test')
      option_value_2 = create(:option_value, value: 'Test1')
      variant_1 = Variant.new()
      variant_1.option_values = [ option_value_1, option_value_2 ]
      variant_1.save
      variant_2 = Variant.new()
      variant_2.option_values = [ option_value_1 ]
      variant_2.save
      option_value_1.update_attribute(:value, 'New test')
    end
```

config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.observers
```

option_value_sweeper.rb

```
class OptionValueSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  include SweepersHelpers
  observe :option_value

  def after_update(option_value)
    puts option_value.value
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no assertion in the spec?

Comment: I got that working, the observer functionality was turned off and in there were some other configurations which were causing the sweeper to run first. Thanks for looking in to this.